# I upgraded from kubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS and now my screen shows up and disappears

Tags: upgrade, screen, flicker

It looks like -flicker-, but contrary to what I could find in Google, it is not to do with Chrome. It is the log-in screen already that shows up occasionally on the screen, and then the screen turns black again. This is the second, main, monitor to my Thinkpad T410s. On the built-in screen everything is fine. But it is so tiny, I do not use it. 
I also came across some random shutdown troubles during my search. I do *not* have any such. 
I would not say that the display flickers, rather the display shows up for spilt-seconds while the larger part of the time the display is simply black.

As last resort: How would I downgrade from here so that I can use the PC again, please?

Here is - on request - the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor
Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command. There is no way to downgrade.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, or at least provides a chance to get closer: I have two of identically the same machines: T410s. Both sit on the identical dock. And the second one has an even larger resolution: 1920x1200.
The second one, however, has no such problems at all.
And: the output of the lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' is also identical to the point. 
What else could I do to narrow down the difference that makes the difference?

Comment: Is any VGA-DVI or similar adapter used?

Comment: In both cases I use the digital output of the docking station.
In both cases the hardware hasn't changed at all. Just upgrading the software.

Comment: Okay, I did the dmesg for both identical machines. Alas, 'diff' wasn't good enough to see the huge similarities (almost all identical). However, a visual inspection brought a clear difference for the item DMAR:$ cat Dmesg_nogood | grep DMAR
[    0.355681] DMAR: BIOS has allocated no shadow GTT; disabling IOMMU for graphics
While the good one shows some 10 DMARs, and at that same position:
[    0.335616] DMAR: Disabling batched IOTLB flush on Ironlake 

Now help me someone to explain this difference, and how I can stimulate this behaviour on the second identical machine, please!

Comment: Allow me one more, please:  
I just found out the difference: one has a deactivated NVIDIA card, it seems:  
DMI: LENOVO 2924WEG/2924WEG, BIOS 6UET70WW (1.50 ) 10/11/2012  
And the other one not:  
DMI: LENOVO 2904FXG/2904FXG, BIOS 6UET70WW (1.50 ) 10/11/2012

Comment: Please don't post additional information to comments. [edit] your question and post it there.